# Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \ln\left(\frac{n^2}{n^2-1}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I made sure it passed the nth term test. Next I thought the easiest way, given that it's wrapped in ln, would be to use log rules to make it $\ln(n^2)-\ln(n^2-1)$ and then compare it to $\dfrac {1}{n^2}$ or $\dfrac {1}{n}$, however I can't get it down to anything conclusive to see if it's convergent or divergent. With the $\ln$ I'm not sure what another way to tackle this would be.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:** $$\ln\left(\dfrac{n^2}{n^2-1}\right)=-\ln(n-1)+2\ln n-\ln(n+1)$$

Comment: By telescoping you can easily find n^th partial summation and ...

Answer (score 3):

Just make further simplifications

> $$ \ln(n^2)-\ln(n^2-1) = \ln(n^2)-\ln(n^2) - \ln(1-\frac{1}{n^2}) = -\ln(1-\frac{1}{n^2})   \sim \frac{1}{n^2}.$$

**Note:**

> $$ \ln(n^2-1) = \ln( n^2 )+\ln(1-1/n^2) .$$

Answer (score 3):

$\ln\left(\dfrac{n^2}{n^2-1}\right) = \ln\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n^2-1}\right)\approx_{0} \dfrac{1}{n^2-1} \to \text{series convergent}$

Answer (score 2):

First, find the Maclaurin series for the following expression: $$\frac{n^2}{n^2-1}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{n^2}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{-2n} \approx1+\frac{1}{n^2}$$ We used the fact that the expression could be rearranged to look like a geometric series. Then, we have $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \approx \frac{1}{n^2}$$ In the last step, we used the Maclaurin series for $\ln(1+x)$. So, compare your original series with $\frac{1}{n^2}$ using the limit comparison test, i.e. compute: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2\ln\left(\frac{n^2}{n^2-1}\right)$$ If this limit is greater than zero, then your original series converges, since $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges.

Comment: Thanks, taking the limit after breaking up ln using log rules seemed to throw me off. When I just did it without I got a constant greater than zero.